# How can I find the rank of $A^6$ if $A$ is a matrix of order $3$ and rank of $A^3$ is $2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have tried it in the following manner. We know that $$rank(XY)\ge rank(X)+rank(Y)-n$$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two matrices of order $n$ and also $$rank(XY) \le \min{\{rank(X),rank(Y)\}}$$ If we take $X=Y=A^3$ then using the above two inequalities we obtain $1\le rank(A^6)\le 2$ i.e. rank of $A^6=1 \text{ or } 2$. Is it correct at all? I have failed to obtain a definite rank of $A^6$ by the above process. Is it ok?

Comment: It seems correct...

Comment: your answer is correct. for more information:  $\dim(\mathcal{R}(A)\cap\mathcal{N}(A))=0  iff  \dim(\mathcal{R}(A))=\dim(\mathcal{R}(A^2)) $

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$. Let $a,b,c$ be the root of characteristic polynomial of $A$ or say eigenvalue of $A$. So $a^3,b^3,c^3$ will be eigenvalue of $A^3$. As kernel of $A^3$ is one dimensional one of the eigen value of $A^3$ will be $0$, say $c^3 = 0$. So $c=0$.

First note $a,b$ simultaneously can't be $0$, in that case characteristic polynomial of $A$ must be $x^3$ and $A^3=0$.

Now we will show neither $a$ nor $b$ is zero. Assume $b=0$ and $a\neq 0$. Using Jordan form, in that case matrix of $A$ w.r.t some basis will be one of the following form
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&0 &0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
a&0 &0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align} 
In either case we will have $A^3$ has rank $1$, since in those case we will have
\begin{align}
A^3 &= \begin{pmatrix}
a^3&0 &0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

So we have neither $a$ nor $b$ equal to $0$.
Now consider the case when $a=b$.  In that case matrix of $A$ w.r.t some basis will be one of the following form
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&0 &0\\
0&a&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
a&1 &0\\
0&a&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align} 
As $a \neq 0$, In either case $A^3$ and $A^6$ both will have rank $2.

Now consider the last case $a,b$ are distinct non zero number. Then there exist a eigenbasis so that matrix of $A$  w.r.t that basis will be of the following form
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&0 &0\\
0&b&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
In this case also $A^3$ and $A^6$ both will have rank $2$.

If $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$, use the fact that $\{v_1,v_2,...v_k\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ iff they are Linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$. So that Real rank of $A$ and complex rank of $A$ remain same.

Comment: These are not the only Jordan forms with rank 2.

Comment: Can it be found by using the concept of eigen value.

Comment: @sfarla what else? can you give me an example?

Comment: Here,rank of A^3=2 then it has two non zero eigen values.Let the eigen values of A^3 are a,b,0.Then eigen values of A^6 are a^2,b^2,0.Can I conclude from here that since A^6 has two non zero eigen values then rank of A^6 is 2.

Comment: one example is the $3\times 3$ Jordan block for the eigenvalue $0$. Of course since we are talking about the third power of a matrix it could not happen (why?). Moreover you are assuming that all the eigenvalues are in the field, that it's in general false if we are not working in a algebrically closed field..

Comment: @Sfarla If $A^3$ is nilpotent then so is $A$, but $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix , so its charactesitic polynomial has to be $x^3$ and hence $A^3 =0$ which is not the case here. And of course I am assuming that our Field is algebraically closed. Sorry for not mentioning that. Although note if  $A$ is real matrix then rank of $A$ over real field and rank of $A$ over complex field are same.

Comment: @Arnab Could you please mention whether you matrix is real or complex in the question?

Comment: @timon I know that case is not possible. For example another case not possible is a $2\times 2$ Jordan block relative to the eigenvalue $0$ and another non-zero eigenvalue. What I meant is that in my opinion finding all the possible Jordan forms is not the "right" way, because there are too many cases to analyze, especially if we don't know the field.

Comment: @Sfarla got your point. I have edited the answer And also trying  for a simple answer wihout considering all such case. Thank you.